# What technique SignalR use in case of non-HTML5 supported browsers?

Tags: signalr

I am new to Signal R and has followed some articles like

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhijmk/what-why-and-how-about-signalr/

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

and has stringently practice

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

But while looking into [What is SignalR ?](http://codepattern.net/Blog/post/What-is-SignalR), the author mentioned that  " **In case of non-HTML5 supported browsers it uses other techniques**."

I am curious to know in detail about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official FAQ (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq):

SignalR uses a fallback mechanism to connect the browser to the server. After an initial negotiation request the following transports are tried in order until a successful connection can be made:

- WebSockets (if the both the server and browser indicate they can support websockets)
- Server Sent Events, aka EventSource (if the browser supports Server Sent Events, which is basically all browsers except Internet Explorer)
- Forever Frame (for Internet Explorer only)
- Ajax long polling

WebSockets is the only true full-duplex connection transport. All other transports listed here use the technique/technology named for the incoming data from the server, and standard Ajax POSTs for sends from the client to the server.